# What is the opposite of escape, in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Right now, it is displayed as:

```
how %26 why
```

It should be:

```
how & why
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

That would be [`unescape()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.unescape).

**2017 Edit**: I should note that `unescape()` has now been deprecated in favour of `decodeURI()` and `decodeURIComponent()`. Also, `escape()` has been deprecated in favour of `encodeURI` and `encodeURIComponent()` respectively.

At least they are fairly obvious opposites.

Answer (score 5):

Try calling [`unescape`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unescape.asp).

Answer (score 2):

**Try `unescape()`**

**Note:**

The deprecated `unescape()` method computes a new string in which hexadecimal escape sequences are replaced with the character that it represents. The escape sequences might be introduced by a function like escape. Because unescape is deprecated, use **decodeURI** or **decodeURIComponent** instead.

Answer (score 0):

you can use *unescape* to remove *escape* characters.

Moreover, *unescape/escape* is not deprecated over *decodeURL/encodeURL* . but *decodeURL/encodeURL* is preferable to **decode/encode** URL.